# get only shorcut files from desktop in powershell

Tags: windows, winforms, powershell, powershell-5.0

my power shell version is

```
5.0
```

In windows 10, to get all files from desktop, i use

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Desktop\
```

This returns only the files but i want to get only the short-cut icons name in that directory.

I also use this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Desktop\ -force|  where {$_.extension -eq ".lnk"}
```

but it also does not work.

Is that possible or is there any better way or is there any administrator or security issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The earlier you filter your results the better and quicker your query will be, so I'd use:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Desktop\ -Filter *.lnk
```

Your path should also probably be c:\users\'username'\desktop or "$($env:userprofile)\desktop"

Comment: If you wanted subfolders you could also add the -Recurse flag